# How to use Joda-Time with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jodatime

I it seems to be a very stupid question, because [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is easy to use that there is no explanation about how to use it in its user guide (and I don’t find useful answers on the web).

I try to use the method of Joda-Time which can calculate the duration between two dates. I have to compare the current date with an other date.

I cannot use `LocalDateTime` because the class does not exist (so I created it), but I saw that "duration" need to implement `ReadableDuration` in the class but this interface does not exist too...

I tried to write :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(juDate);
```

and

```
public class LocalDateTime implements ReadableDuration{

    public LocalDateTime() {
    }
}
```

I have install Joda-Time by dependency on [Maven](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), I have the 2.9.1 version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Can you explain to a newbie how to do, please ?

Comment: Can you share code which you tried?

Comment: I don't think Jodatime don't have good documenation. 
What about these links? 
http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/ 
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html

Comment: This sounds very much like the library is simply not in your class path at compile time.

Comment: Share your maven dependency ... Did you did "mvn clean install" ?

Comment: @SanjayaPandey "I don't think Jodatime don't have good documenation." Are you saying you don't think it has good documentation, or that it does have good documentation? Double-negatives are confusing.

Comment: dont use jodatime anymore ... JRE8 is out.

Comment: @AndyTurner I am saying that It have good documentation.....  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## java.time

The time api has been reworked in JDK 8 and resembles a lot Joda-Time (I think Joda-Time is implementation of some JSR).

Citation http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java.
>   From Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time
>   (JSR-310).

So just create a JDK 8 project and your LocalDate and LocalTime classes should be available in package java.time

After that just follow official oracle tutorial:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

GLHF

Comment: Right click on your project -> proeprties -> java build path -> Libraries tab and make sure you have JRE System Library [jdk1.8.0 ..]

Comment: Yes, it is not 1.8.0, sorry

Comment: Joda-Time calls itself "de facto standard" but is strictly speaking not a standard because it is not an implementation of any JSR (just a 3rd-party library although very popular and wide-spread). The project owner has used Joda-Time as orientation but not as base to implement the JSR-310 (java.time-API in Java-8) from the scratch. So both APIs use partially similar class names (like "LocalDate") but are not compatible with each other. And attention, Joda-Time is not written as "Yoda" ;-)

Comment: I change to JavaSE-1.8 (java-8-oracle) on eclipse window > preference, then on eclipse project > properties and finally on my project > properties. Duration cannot find "between"

Comment: @MenoHochschild hey man, it's StarWars 7 week soon :). But I agree, it is not a JSR implementation. However the quote states it - better migrate to JSR version in JDK 8

Comment: @Chènevis `java.time.Duration`-class has one `between`-method. Please check your imports (for example XML and JavaFX also have such a class). There are at least two (or even 3) classes with name `Duration` in JDK. Watch also out for `java.time.Period` and the class `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`. All three classes give you some support for evaluating durations.

Comment: This is not a proper answer to the question and I don't get why it has been accepted. The question is how to use joda-time with maven. @Chènevis was not asking for a work around. What if I have a Project which I'm developing on since months and years and I cannot "just" upgrade to JDK8 for reasons AND I need to include joda-time as a maven dependecy?!

Answer (score 3):

Have you done the following in your pom.xml file? :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, after you've added that entry, you have to do mvn clean install from your IDE or command-line. Then it should be available as an import in your project. If you are using another build system, I would like to refer to the following page: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/dependency-info.html.

Don't create the classes yourself, it is a sign that the project is not imported through your build system.

You should be able to do the following in your code above your class declaration:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
```

Then you are able to use it.

**Edit:**
As an addition to the above information, I can see that you accepted the answer that suggested that you should switch to Java 8. While in this situation, that might work, but what if you need other packages (dependencies) which are not available through upgrading to a higher Java version?

I suggest you should read upon build systems like Maven and Gradle. Those are mostly used in Java projects. Just playing around with it could give insights.